# android crashes after using setMyLocationEnabled on mapcallback on actual device

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to use google map v2 on my android application. everything works on emulator but if i use setMyLocationEnabled(true) on my map it will crash on actual device.

the device is lg x-cam using android v6.

here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.latest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.latest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.latest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" 
         >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="my valid api key is here"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my MainActivity :

```
package com.example.latest;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
         map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
         map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

my activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Post full *stack trace*. If you working with `SDK` version `6.0` then you need to provide `Run Time permission`.

Comment: Make sure you request the correct permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @jaydroider what code should i use in my activity for this matter ? can u be more specific ? thank u

Comment: @KenWolf i think i should use location permission on run time, can u give me an example ?

Comment: @MehdiNazari I agree - everything  you need is in the link. Good luck!

Comment: @MehdiNazari Check and follow my answer below will make easy for you.